# data not saved on join table

Tags: jpa, join

I generated entities using NetBeans (EclipseLink JPA) based on the following diagram:

[image]

The relevant generated code is:

`Course`

```
@JoinTable(name = "course_software", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "software_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Software> softwareList;
```

`Software`

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "softwareList")
  private List<Course> courseList;
```

The problem is with `Course` entity. When I try to persist it as follows

```
getFacade().create(currentCourse);
currentCourse.setSoftwareList(selectedSoftware);
```

then a record is created in `course`, but nothing is created in `course_software` join table.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You wanna say: _"but nothing is saved on my course_software join table"_ ?

Comment: Pardon me for that. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to specify the `referencedColumnName` attributes of `@JoinColumn` annotations as long as the columns referenced in the joined table are already primary keys.